# Use gradle to build a jarfile from other jarfiles

Tags: gradle, jar

I have what should be a simple problem: I have a directory full of jarfiles, and I want to use gradle (v4.4.1) to combine the contents of these jarfiles into a single jarfile (i.e., when I do jar tf big-jar.jar, I want to see a bunch of classes, not a bunch of jars). I tried the following:

```
task bigJar(type: Jar) {
    inputs.dir "$distLibsJar"
    outputs.file "$distDir/big-jar.jar"

    destinationDir = file("$distDir")
    baseName = "big-jar"
    from("$distLibsDir")
}
```

but this produces a jarfile with other jars as its contents rather than the contents of those other jars as the contents of the combined jar.

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In this case best way to proceed is with a **shadow** jar. for this you can have this kind of configuration in build.gradle .posting some sample

```
 apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

           shadowJar {
               zip64 true
               //classifier "shadow" can be mentioned according to need
            mergeServiceFiles()
            artifacts {
                shadow(tasks.shadowJar.archivePath) {
                    builtBy shadowJar
                }
            }
        }
        artifacts {
                archives shadowJar
        }

    distZip {
            dependsOn shadowJar
            //appendix='software'
            eachFile { file ->
                String path = file.relativePath
                file.setPath(path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1,path.length()))
            }

            doLast{
                        //operation to perform


            }
        }
        distributions {
                main {
                    contents {
                       //from and to can be mentioned here
                    }
                }

            }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Have posted an answer as comment would have been too big to read.